# What are Linker Symbols __TMC_END__ and __TMC_LIST__ for?

Tags: c, linker, ld

I've asked [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17605034/linker-script-relocate-section) and stumbled across the `__TMC_END__` symbol that seems to be generated by the linker. I don't know what it's purpose is and the only useful reference to it is [this bug](http://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=13621) which doesn't explain much about why it is there. The but does however, make a reference to a similar symbol `__TMC_LIST__`.

Does anybody know what these are used for?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Doing more searching I've come across [this bit of code](https://github.com/mirrors/gcc/blob/master/libgcc/crtstuff.c#L11) that suggests that these symbols are to do with the `tm_clone_table` which I've understood to have something to do with *transactional memory*. Following the bread crumbs lead me to [this GCC Wiki explanation](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/TransactionalMemory).

Comment: Another interesting fact: `crtstuff.c` is compiled into `crtend.o`, which is passed by default to the linker by gcc.